# Filtering data by category JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm new to javascript.
We have a category selection function. Can you please help to suggest a filtering function that, when choosing a specific category, will pull up all blogs from this category by ID?

### JavaScript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.category-filter_item').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document
      .querySelector('.category-filter_item.active')
      .classList.remove('active');
    el.classList.add('active');
```

We have something like the following code on the blog page. First we get all the **available categories**, then a **list of all blogs**.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="category-filter" id="filter">
     <div class="category-filter_item active">All</div>
     @foreach($categories as $category)
     <div class="category-filter_item">{{ $category->title }}</div>
     @endforeach
</div>

@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <div class="blog-list {{ $blog->category_id}}">
        <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

### Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::all();
        $categories = Category:all();

        return view('blog', compact('blogs', 'categories'));
    }
```

Development environment **Laravel**

### Alternation

```
@foreach ($blogs as $index => $blog)
    <div class="blog-list">
        @if ($index % 2 === 1) 
            <div class="blog blog--left" >
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @else

            <div class="blog blog--right">
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think you need to create a relationship between categories and blog posts

Comment: they already have a relationship between them

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Isotop.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) it would be easy and nice.

or use this code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="category-filter" id="filter">
    <div class="category-filter_item active" data-filter="*">All</div>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="category-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }}</div>
    @endforeach
</div>

    @foreach($blogs as $blog)
    <div class="blog-list category_{{ $blog->category_id}}">
        <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endsection


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>

<script>
$('.category-filter_item').click(function(){
    $('.category-filter_item').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    var dataFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.blog-list').hide()
    $(dataFilter).show()
})
</script>
```

Comment: You can ask another question, I still have an alternation of blogs in my code. This feature you gave hides all unnecessary blogs, and when you go to the selected category, the alternation collapses. Can you do something to make the alternation of blogs work again when choosing a category?

Comment: How the alternation works for me, I posted below in the topic